# How to make a Palindrome with a sed command?

Tags: linux, sed, palindrome

I'm trying to find the code that searches all palindromes in a dictionary file

this is what I got atm which is wrong :

```
sed -rn '/^([a-z])-([a-z])\2\1$/p' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Can somebody explain the code as well.

Found the right answer.

`sed -n '/^\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\2\1$/p' /usr/share/dict/words`

I have no idea why I used `-`
I also don't have an explenation for the `\` ater each group

Comment: Instead of just flatly asking for an explanation, maybe you could concoct and provide an example of how you think this works? That way you'd show that you've put some effort into it. Explain also why do you think your own explanation is not working.

Comment: @SamiLaine 
Sure, that's exactly why I'm asked for an explanation on the right answer. Here we go : I start my sed command with –rn because I’m using extended regular expressions so I don’t have to escape things. I use –n for automatic printing of pattern space. ‘/^ = Begin with the following : I want my reg expr to be started with an exact combination of letters from a-z followed by the same exact combination of letters. I use \1 followed by \2 to repeat the 2 captured groups. I personally think something is wrong with my quotes “()” “[]” and “-“

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grep command as explained [here](http://www.thelinuxtips.com/2010/10/find-palindrome-using-grep-command/)

```
grep -w  '^\(.\)\(.\).\2\1'
```

**explanation** The grep command searches for the first any three letters  by using (.)(.).  after that we are searching the same 2nd character and 1st character is occuring or not.

The above grep command will find out only 5 letters palindrome words.

**extended version** is proposed as well on that page; and works correctly for the first line but then crashes... there is surely some good to keep and maybe to adapt...

Guglielmo Bondioni proposed a single RE that finds all palindromes up to 19 characters long using 9 subexpressions and 9 back-references:

```
grep -E -e '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1' file
```

You can extend this further as much as you want :)

Comment: I have to use sed in this exercice

Comment: the grep cmd line didn't go on my box (`grep (GNU grep) 2.18`), errMsg:`grep: regexec.c:1401: pop_fail_stack: Assertion `num >= 0' failed.[1]    25767 abort (core dumped)`

Comment: @Kent yes I know, I have the same Issue, that's why I added the warning that it has some good but might need some adaptations... I'm not going to pursuit perfection here since apparently he needs a sed expression...

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'print if $_ eq reverse' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: +1; not strictly what the OP is asking for (in terms of tools used), but you can't beat the elegance.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it, but while regex may be able to cook your breakfast, I don't think it can find a palindrome. According to the all-knowing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Computation_theory):

> In the automata theory, a set of all palindromes in a given alphabet is a typical example of a language that is context-free, but not regular. This means that it is impossible for a computer with a finite amount of memory to reliably test for palindromes. (For practical purposes with modern computers, this limitation would apply only to incredibly long letter-sequences.)
>
> In addition, the set of palindromes may not be reliably tested by a deterministic pushdown automaton which also means that they are not LR(k)-parsable or LL(k)-parsable. When reading a palindrome from left-to-right, it is, in essence, impossible to locate the "middle" until the entire word has been read completely.

So a regular expression won't be able to solve the problem based on the problem's nature, but a computer program (or `sed` examples like @NeronLeVelu or @potong) will work.

Answer (score 0):

explanation of your code

```
sed -rn '/^([a-z])-([a-z])\2\1$/p' /usr/share/dict/words
```

select and print line that correspond to :

A first (starting the line) small alphabetic character followed by `-` followed by another small alaphabetic character (could be the same as the first) followed by the last letter of the previous group followed by the first letter Letter1-Letter2Letter2Letter1 and the no other element (end of line)

```
sample:

a-bba

a is first letter
b second letter
b is \2
a is \1
```

But it's a bit strange for any work unless it came from a very specific dictionnary (limited to combination by example)

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 22: Invalid back reference

Comment: missing the second `)` and i think it's after first [a-z] so there is 2 simple group of letter. I adapt the post with this

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s/[^[:alpha:]]//g;H;x;s/\n/&&/;ta;:a;s/\n(.*)\n(.)/\n\2\1\n/;ta;G;/\n(.*)\n\n\1$/IP;d' file
```

This copies the original string(s) to the hold space (HS), then removes everything but alpha characters from the string(s) and appends this to the HS. The second copy is then reversed and the current string(s) and the reversed copy compared. If the two strings are equal then the original string(s) is printed out otherwise the line is deleted.